# select a single value though a table in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

The table has these columns:`category_id`, `category_name`, and `category_parent_name`

I would like to get `category_id` by using `category_name`. I searched online, and the code is like below:

`$ad_cat` is the category name.

```
global $wpdb;
  $tbl_categories = $wpdb->prefix."awpcp_categories";
   $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $tbl_categories where category_name =".$ad_cat );
$category_id=intval($retrieve_data->category_id);
```

I echo'ed category name and `id` for testing. The name shows fine, but `id` is always `0`.
Any idea or solution?

Comment: What if you don't use `intval`?

Comment: It pops up an error message without intval: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'ad_category_id' at row 1

Answer (score 1):

It says the error because your query isn't correct. Try:

```
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT category_name FROM $tbl_categories 
                                  where category_name ='".$ad_cat."'" )
```

Comment: I fixed the query to pull the correct column versus the full table with `*`.

Comment: No it doesn't work. I also echo'ed $retrieve_data, it is "dataArray". I think there is some error in $wpdb structure.

Comment: the var_dump is array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#483 (1) { ["category_name"]=> string(20) "Fitness and Exercise" } }

Comment: pop your query in PHPMyAdmin or something and see if your query runs. I think `$wpdb->prefix."awpcp_categories";` is wrong

Comment: Okay I figure it out. It should use get_var instead of get results. Thanks for the help!